Why do I get an "Incorrect type" error when setting codeActionsOnSave?
I am following this doc by Wes Bos to set up both ESLint. I also wanted to make it such that the set up automatically helps me reformat my code on save. However, this part of the set up is not working.
After some investigation, I found out that in my settings.json file, where I have:
{
    "emmet.extensionsPath": [
        "/home/lauweibin/Documents/"
    ],
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
    "liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles": [
        ".vscode/**",
        "**/*.scss",
        "**/*.sass",
        "**/*.ts"
    ],
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "emmet.preferences": {
        "output.inlineBreak": 1
    },
    "explorer.confirmPasteNative": false,
    "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "never",
    "editor.cursorBlinking": "smooth",
    "github.copilot.editor.enableAutoCompletions": true,
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "[javascript][javascriptreact][typescript][typescriptreact]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": false
    },
    "eslint.enable": true,
    "eslint.run": "onType",
    "eslint.validate": [
        "javascript",
        "javascriptreact",
        "typescript",
        "typescriptreact"
    ]
}

The part that is not working is true in:
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.fixAll.eslint": true
},

I am getting an Incorrect type. Expected "string" error.
I also tried restarting VSCode and when I come back, true always gets changed to explicit. I am quite confused as to why this doesn't work because I did exactly as what the doc said and it's supposed to work.
Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Is there something you don't understand in the error message?

I understood what the error message meant. What I don't understand is why there is an error message when I followed the doc exactly and felt like there shouldn't have been an error

The reason you get this error, which I think may be just a warning, is that boolean for codeActionsOnSave has been deprecated since this PR. You should now use string values instead.
Here is the relevant part of the docs on this property:

As of today, the following enums are supported:

explicit (default): Triggers Code Actions when explicitly saved. Same as true.
always: Triggers Code Actions when explicitly saved and on Auto Saves from window or focus changes.
never: Never triggers Code Actions on save. Same as false.


